# SOLR highlighting issue

Tags: php, solr, highlight

While using SOLR highlighting , some of the times I am not getting correct data. For example If I am using "come up" I am getting highlighted result as *come**up*. Is their any configuration settings for displaying highlighting result as *come up* ?

Comment: check how your fields are being analyzed, tokenized that would give you an idea.

Comment: Could you add snippet of doc matching the query around your term?